# DevExpress: How to change the backcolor of a SearchLookUpEdit control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to change the BackColor of the PopUp control that is shown if you select the DropDown button in an SearchLookUpEdit but I can't find an appropriate property to do this.

[image: Example]

Btw. I use a defaultLookAndFeel object with Style set to "UltraFlat" so I can't define it within the skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from devexpress support: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q345598.aspx

```
Private Sub SearchLookUpEdit1_Popup(sender As System.Object, _
        e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchLookUpEdit1.Popup

    Dim popupControl As Control = CType(sender, IPopupControl).PopupWindow
    popupControl.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
    Dim lc As LayoutControl = CType(popupControl.Controls(2).Controls(0), LayoutControl)
    Dim lcgroup As LayoutControlGroup = CType(lc.Items(0), LayoutControlGroup)
    lcgroup.AppearanceGroup.BackColor = Color.LightBlue

End Sub
```